# How to get a value from Select-String

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I have several files in a folder, those are .xml files.

I want to get a value from those files.
A line in the file, could look like this:

```
<drives name="Virtual HD ATA Device" deviceid="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0" interface="IDE" totaldisksize="49,99">
```

What i'm trying to do is get the value 49,99 in this case.

I am able to get the line out of the file with:

```
$Strings = Select-String -Path "XML\*.xml" -Pattern totaldisksize

foreach ($String in $Strings) {
        Write-Host "Line is" $String

}
```

But getting just the value in "" i don't get how. I've also played around with

```
$Strings.totaldisksize
```

But no dice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line as follows:

```powershell
$(select-string totaldisksize .\XML\*.xml).line -replace '.*totaldisksize="(\d+,\d+)".*','$1'
```

The `Select-String` will give you a collection of objects that contains information about the match. The `line` property is the one you're interested in, so you can pull that directly.

Using the `-replace` operator, every time the `.line` property is a match of `totaldisksize`, you can run the regex on it. The `$1` replacement will grab the group in the regex, the group being the part in parentheses `(\d+,\d+)` which will match one or more digits, followed by a comma, followed by one or more digits.

This will print to screen because by default powershell will print an object to the screen. Because you're only accessing the `.line` property, that's the only bit that's printed and also only *after* the replacement has been run.

If you wanted to explicitly use a `Write-Host` to see the results, or do anything else with them, you could store to a variable as follows:

```powershell
$sizes = $(select-string totaldisksize .\XML\*.xml).line -replace '.*totaldisksize="(\d+,\d+)".*','$1'
$sizes | % { Write-Host $_ }
```

The above stores the results to an array, `$sizes`, and you iterate over it by piping it to the `Foreach-Object` or `%`. You can then access the array elements with `$_` inside the block.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Any chance i could bother you to explain it? I don't get how it's writtes with no write-host.

Comment: It seems to get the whole line if there are no , in the value between the "". Like: <drives name="disk 1" deviceid="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0" interface="SAS" totaldisksize="50"> It is possible it could both understand "50,2" and "50"? Thanks.

Comment: Answer to my last comment is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075793/find-number-between-quotes/27075804?noredirect=1#comment42662795_27075804

Answer (score 0):

But.. but.. PowerShell knows XML.

```
$XMLfile = '<drives name="Virtual HD ATA Device" deviceid="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0" interface="IDE" totaldisksize="49,99"></drives>'
$XMLobject = [xml]$XMLfile
$XMLobject.drives.totaldisksize
```

Output

```
49,99
```

Or walk the tree and return the content of "drives":

```
$XMLfile = @"
<some>
  <nested>
     <tags>       
        <drives someOther="stuff" totaldisksize="49,99" freespace="22,33">
        </drives>
     </tags>
  </nested>
</some>
"@

$drives = [xml]$XMLfile | Select-Xml -XPath "//drives" | select -ExpandProperty node
```

Output

```
PS> $drives

someOther         totaldisksize           freespace
---------         -------------           ---------
stuff                     49,99               22,33

PS> $drives.freespace
22,33
```

XPath query of "//drives" = Find all nodes named "drives" anywhere in the XML tree.
Reference: Windows PowerShell Cookbook 3rd Edition (Lee Holmes). Page 930.

Comment: Okay.. What if the line does not look like that?

Comment: What's common between those files? Can i take "totaldisksize" as common ChildNode property? Can i take <drives>?

Comment: A line will always contain <drive> sometimes I need the totaldisksize,  sometimes freespace.

Comment: Updated my answer to walk the tree.

Comment: Thank you. But this is a case where there are several xml files.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about `powershell` but if you prefer using `python` below is the way of doing it.

```
import re

data = open('file').read()
item = re.findall('.*totaldisksize="([\d,]+)">', data)
print(item[0])
```

Output

```
49,99
```