# Find number between quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

So I have this line, well several.

```
<drives name="drive 1" deviceid="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0" interface="SCSI" totaldisksize="136,7">
```

and

```
<drives name="drive 1" deviceid="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0" interface="SCSI" totaldisksize="1367">
```

I have this line which match the the number between the quotes:

```
$(Select-String totaldisksize $Path\*.xml).line -replace '.*totaldisksize="(\d+,\d+)".*','$1'
```

Which will match 136,7 but not 1367.

Is it possible to match both?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make the `,` in your regex as optional by adding the `?` quantifier next to `,`.

```
$(Select-String totaldisksize $Path\*.xml).line -replace '.*totaldisksize="(\d+,?\d+)".*','$1'
```

**OR**

```
$(Select-String totaldisksize $Path\*.xml).line -replace '.*totaldisksize="(\d+(?:,\d+)*)".*','$1'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aJ1xT8/1)

**Regular Expression:**

```
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                           times):
    ,                        ','
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
  )*                       end of grouping
)                        end of \1
```

Comment: Yeah, I really don't get the demo. My mind just cannot understand the syntax. What if it had to also match 136.7? And thank you.

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
$xmlfile = 'C:\path\to\output.xml'

& cscript sydi-server.vbs -t. -ex -o$xmlfile

[xml]$sysinfo = Get-Content $xmlfile

$driveinfo = $sysinfo.SelectNodes('//drives') |
             select name, @{n='DiskSize';e={[Double]::Parse($_.totaldisksize)}}
```

Note: [Do not parse XML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171). It will corrupt your soul and make catgirls die in pain.